# mapview shows 0,0 location when fetching value from xml with space in address

Tags: objective-c

i'm quite novice in iphone s/w development i was on an application it requires to start mapview from the location specified in xml file but in xml file "address" having some spaces in it like "3300 Providence Dr Ste 6" but mkmapview show the location 0,0 instead to find in google api.
so what i'll do to remove those spaces.

i have used google code  :  @"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",string

thanks in advance

with regards
prateek bhanot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to URL-encode the parameter:

```
NSString *encodedAddress = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", encodedAddress];
```